# Eclipse > Java > open linked resources sources (.java instead of .class )?

Tags: java, eclipse

I have 2 projects, A and B

project B have in his build path > libraries the class folder of A (Eclipse also recognized that there is a "Source attachment" and added it.

Both A and B are in the same workspace.

When I <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + click into a function of project A referenced into a file of B Eclipse open the `.class` file of A. But if I need to edit the `.java` version of that file I must manually look for the filename in project A and open it from project explorer.

There isn't an easier way to go from a linked resource to -> `.java` file of his source or to go from `.class` to `.java` in easier way than manually expand folders and open the file?

Comment: Have you tried adding Project A into the Projects tab of Configure Build Path window for Project B?

Comment: no but build path is the most external referencing i can do i mean, i need to indicate where the A/src folder , build path only refecence  to 
A/dist (.class files)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to open a search Dialog.

But you should add B as a dependent project of A (and remove it from the classpath).

[image]

Comment: i've tryed to do that (add B as dependent of project A, also tryed to to the inverted thing (add in A->orijects project B as required both in java build PATH as per your screenshot), but then, after removing the class folder from classpath  all " import A.*" from project B stopped working (underlined in red ) and no ctrl+click works...

Comment: @Francesco does A need B or does B need A?

Comment: A is imported into B anyway using this "java build path -> projects -> add " from project B (the correct way i think.. ) seems to not recognize A classes doing "import A.***"

Comment: is A a correctly set-up eclipse java project, with a designated src folder? This should work without any problems. Maybe try a Project-->Clean?

Comment: project A is ok, in A/bin i have all classes up2date and updated after each save in A, project B imports works fine if i add A (using "add class folder" pointing to A/bin and with also the source attachment into "A/src"  and this is the most smart way to do that i've found (imports works fine and source should be also linked and it is! because when i  ctrl+click a function from A  used into B it open the correct A/classname.class showing the source instead (strange because it's a .class file) , but i have found no way to edit that file without reopening the .java file from the project A

Comment: the problem may be that eclipse know that i'm working on project B and avoid me to editing code from other external project without have switched the project  focus in "project explorer" window in the workspace )

Comment: the strange problem i have is this in project B
\n
import A.aaaa
\n
if i ctrl+click "aaaa"
eclipse open a file called aaaa.class showing the content of aaaa.java 

and i found no way to edit aaaa.java from there without re-searching and opening it from "project explorer" window

Comment: if eclipse opens the class you have it somewhere in your classpath, you should remove everthing from A from the classpath in B. I'd suggest setting eclipse up from scratch. Remove the projects. Delete the .projects file in the project Folder and reimport.

Comment: i don't have in the classpath only in library of the build-path.. this is the only way to have imports working for me.. but even if the included library is from the workspace with both src and bin defined, i cannot switch to one project to another with a simple click on a class reference...

Comment: after some retry now eclipse seems to accept imports even if the project is not in the build-path->libraries but only in the  build-path ->"projects" so probably the problem was that i need to redo everything some times before get this working ;)

Answer (score 8):

Go to Project->Properties->Java Build Path.

In Order and Export keep all the src files on top and selected.

Eclipse will now pick .java over .class files

Answer (score 5):

Another case solution:

> One neat feature of Eclipse (and other IDEs) is that you can hold CTRL
>   and click on a function or variable to go to its definition.
>
> A problem which may occur in Eclipse is that it opens the .class file
>   (the compiled file) instead of opening the .java file when you do
>   this. This is probably caused by the order of the entries in the
>   .classpath file.
>
> Go to your project directory and open the .classpath file. Move all
>   entires of type classpathentry with attribute kind="src" to the top of
>   the file (or at least above any entries with kind "output").
>
> Restart Eclipse and the problem should be fixed.

Found on [this page](http://www.herikstad.net/2011/04/eclipse-opens-class-instead-of-java.html)

Answer (score 3):

Remove project A from "build path > libraries" and put it in "build path > projects".

Comment: same suggestion of "oers", i've tryed but didn't worked also all import A.* are missing in source code of B

Comment: @Francesco: Also remember that if project B depends on project A, A must be in "build path > projects" of B.