# Eclipse Open Declaration opens class files instead of java

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, class, navigation

I have a multimodule Maven project in my eclipse, with around 40 projects. Navigation among classes was working fine within the same project and within different projects. However, this has stopped working and I don't know why. 
Now, `Open Declaration` is always opening the generated class files, under `Maven dependencies`, instead of the java ones, even to the java class that is right below the current one.
All projects have the Maven's `Workspace resolution` enabled.
Also, I still can open the java file with `CTRL+SHIFT+T`.

I've been googling and stackoverflowing, but the answers I found didn't help much

Any ideas?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Right click on the project -> Properties -> Maven. What is the state of the checkbox?

Comment: "Resolve dependencies from Workspace projects" was not checked in some projects. Checking it solved the problem. I wonder what I did to unmakr it  :-?

Comment: Even though I have it checked, it still doesn't work for some reason.. keeps opening class files... I am using Eclipse Oxygen..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [eclipse > java > open linked resources sources (.java instead of .class )?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8603292/eclipse-java-open-linked-resources-sources-java-instead-of-class)

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the project -> Properties -> Maven.
Check the "Resolve dependencies from Workspace projects".
That should do the trick.
Tribute to Aleksandr M.

Answer (score 0):

Update dependency jar versions in main project pom.xml, to match with the versions of dependency maven projects which are having source code